# Iterate, Check for condition & delete accordingly : Firebase Realtime

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using **Firebase realtime database**. Below is the structure

[image]

**Problem Statement**: Over a list of "Users", I need to delete child who's having coins = 0

So far I'm stuck here

```
DatabaseReference deleteRef = dbref.child("Users").child("coins");

Query deleteQuery = deleteRef.orderByValue().equalTo("0");
deleteQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                child.getRef().setValue(null);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to order the list by the child `coins` like here:

```
 DatabaseReference deleteRef = dbref.child("Users");
 Query deleteQuery = deleteRef.orderByChild("coins").equalTo("0");
 deleteQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
             for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                 child.getRef().setValue(null);
             }
          }
      }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
           throw databaseError.toException();
       }
});
```